# jQuery UI Autocomplete not working in IE - error: SCRIPT5007

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to use jQuery UI Autocomplete with a remote JSON source. Everything is working fine in FF and chrome, but in IE the Autocomplete dropdown does not trigger. I get a strange error:

> SCRIPT5007: Unable to get value of the property 'call': object is null or undefine

Here is my code for autocomplete:

```
        $("#product").autocomplete({
         source: function( request, response ) {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'https://secure1.valuecentric.com/Portal/ds_products.cfm',
                type: 'GET',
                data: request,
                success: function( data ) {
                    // feeding back to jquery autocomplete 
                    response(data );
                }
            })
            },
        minLength: 1,
        autoFocus: true,
        select: function(event, ui){
            //alert(ui.item.id);
            query = ui.item.id;
            drawChart(ui.item.id);
        }
    });
```

You can see the issue live here: http://vciq.com/index.php/component/datastore/

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: Where is the `call` property being used? I think you're missing some relevant code here.

Comment: If this is a cross-domain request you'll need JSONP.

Comment: @andrewWhitaker add it to the answers selection, so I can give you credit :) I did jsonp for all the other ajax request on that page, guess I forgot for autocomplete:/ thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're doing a cross-domain request. If this is the case you'll have to use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP):

```
source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://secure1.valuecentric.com/Portal/ds_products.cfm',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        data: request,
        success: function( data ) {
            // feeding back to jquery autocomplete 
            response(data);
        }
    });
},
```

See the remote with [JSONP example](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) for a working example using JSONP.